# Get audio spectrum from command line as a text

Tags: audio, command-line

```
sox audio.wav -n spectrum
```

Makes picture - not suitable for further automatic processing

I want something like this:

```
$ cat audio.wav | calculate_spectrum - 
0.2
0.5
0.3
4.6
0.2
5.3
...
```

Output should be easily consumable by other text-oriented command line tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it is SoX's other mode:

```
sox audio.wav -n stat -freq
0.000000  3.747641
1.953125  4.574969
3.906250  4.452487
5.859375  3.809817
7.812500  3.400568
...
292.968750  8887.592773
294.921875  9049.043945
296.875000  26993.902344
298.828125  134480.718750
300.781250  275895.437500
302.734375  14540.191406
304.687500  7592.689453
...
Rough   frequency:          299
```